# Iterate `std::vector<std::string>` from Go?

Tags: c++, go, swig

I'm trying to use a C++ library from Go. I also have little experience with Go.

My C++ method looks like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> getAttribute(const std::string key);
```

I have this in my `.swigcxx` file:

```
%include "std_string.i"
%include "std_vector.i"

%include "MyCode.h"

%template(StringVector) std::vector<std::string>;

%{
  #include "MyCode.h"
%}
```

But Go doesn't want to let me access it. I've printed out some info via:

```
attribs := ipuInfo.GetAttribute("foo")
fmt.Printf("%T\n", attribs)
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", attribs)
```

And I get:

```
bar.SwigcptrStringVector
<random number - address perhaps?>
```

But I can't work out how to get to the individual contents of the vector. I've tried:

```
for index, val := range bar.GetAttribute("foo") {
}
```

But that gives:

```
cannot range over bar.GetAttribute("foo") (type interface {})
```

I've also tried calling a `.Capacity()` method on it but it isn't declared (from https://blog.nobugware.com/post/2020/c-bindings-in-go-and-swig/). I've also tried `attribs[0]` and it doesn't like that either.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Many thanks.

Comment: Does, e.g. [this](https://blog.nobugware.com/post/2020/c-bindings-in-go-and-swig/) help?

Comment: That's where I got the reference to calling `.Capacity()`. Sadly it also fails because `Capacity` and `Get` are undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's a problem with function overloading. I had 2 `getAttribute` functions with the same name and different parameters. When I rename the method so that it's unique, `Capacity()` and `Get()` work (although `range` doesn't).

It looks like Swig tried to generate wrapper code to call the correct method, but couldn't deal with different return types

Comment: `range` in Go is only defined for the built-in iterable kinds (slice, array, map, channel, string). It can't be used for interface values.